# How to manipulate structure members using bitwise operations?

Tags: c

For example, for a structure:

```
struct name{
 int a;
 char b;
 float c;
}g;
g.b='X';
```

Now I would like to access structure member `b` using bitwise operators(`<<`,`>>` etc.) and change it to `'A'`.
Is it possible to access structure members using such operators??

Comment: The only operators that access structure members are `.` and `->`.

Comment: You mean instead of doing `g.b = 'A'` you want something like `someoperation(g) = 'A'`?

Comment: yes Iluvatar, using bitwise operations by accessing the individual member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise operations on struct's doesn't make to much sense because of padding and  more importantly it's just killing the purpose of having a struct in the first place. Bitwise operation are as the name said to operate on bit's in variable. Struct variables usually (if they're not packed) will be padded so until you pack them you wouldn't have guarantee where they are to access them but if you want to ask if you can, yes you can, but you would have to cast struct g to let's say 32 bit value then if two variables would be in this space you could use bit operation on this casted value. If it's necessary you can create union from your struct and have raw variable as one union part, and structure as the other option, then you can manipulate bitwise on raw variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data by getting offset of b. I know, this code does not look good.But it serve your purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct name
{
        int a;
        char b;
        float c;
}g;

int main()
{
        g.b='X';
        int y=0;

        int offset = &((struct name *)NULL)->b; // Find Offset of b
        char *p = (char *)&g;
        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<offset;i++)
        {
                ++p;
        }

        *p=*p|(1<<0);

       // *p = 'A';

        printf("........%c\n",g.b);

}
```

Comment: Hi, good job Sumit. I understood from your code how we can access certain member inside structure via byte-by-byte access using char pointer. But, can you help me to access the members via bits. This question was asked in an interview at a company, so i am curious!

Comment: @abinjacob I have modified my code. But i think, interviewer was asking about bit filed in structure and koper89 told Bitwise operations on struct's doesn't make to much sense because of padding.

Answer (score -1):

there's a way, you have to copy the structure content into a variable (size of your struct), then manipulate the variable and finally copy the variable content back into the struct using memset.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.